# How to import a Google calendar so that it can be styled?

Tags: datetime, feeds, javascript

I am wondering if anyone has any ideas regarding solutions for a custom/styled Google Calendar embed on a Drupal Website. I have a client that would like their events updated via Google calendar but is displeased with the look of Google Calendar.

I have tried tons of different modules, but nothing seems to really work well. The [FullCalendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) module came the closest, but the calendar appeared empty (same for other modules as well - just no events appeared in it).

I did try using the Aggregator module, but it includes some extra fields and the information shows up in Spanish for some reason!

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out a way to just import these freaking Google Calendar events, or embed the calendar in a way that it is styleable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are embedding it using iframe, you cannot style it with your own css or javascript as this would be considered **cross site scripting**.

Basically you cannot style or alter anything that is not in your own domain.

The only possible way to style it would be if Google Calendar has a setting on their website to change the style, but you would only be able to do that through their website.

Comment: Right, I know embedding it like normal isn't an option since you can't style the iFrame. That's why I was looking for other options like a module or a way to import it as a feed and then style it after.